# Github Action fails to build on Mac, but works on Windows and Linux -> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: macos, github-actions, arm64, godot, conan

So, I'm building part of an application I'm working on using a Github Action. This Github Action fetches libraries used from conan center and then build a lib for the use within a Godot 3 Programm. This build process works fine in the example given by the guy who made the plugin:

[Fully working build in a minimal example](https://github.com/samsface/godot-native-example/actions/runs/4269081000)

The problem is when I try build my version, that has the "TagLib" library included and used in a bunch of code, the build only works for Ubuntu and Windows, but not for Mac.

I have looked through the build log and there are no errors left I could find and I even made sure to eliminate every warning, so that would not cause any problems. The problem still consists though and I'm frankly out of ideas what to do.

The build always seems to fail with these few lines at the end:

```
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libVeles.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Veles.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

The full failing build is here, if anyone wants to take a look:

[Failing build of mine](https://github.com/LyffLyff/VelesNative/actions/runs/4297368506)

If anyone has any idea on what the problem could be, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "ld: warning: ignoring file [...], building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah found it, apparently the TagLib version was not compatible with the newest arm64 / M1-Mac versions and needed to be downgraded to only work with older MAC-CPUs